# problems with php-cli

Tags: centos, php, php-ini

i have some strange problem with my php-cli, when in ruining `php --info` i see that php uses `/etc/php.ini`, and something strange when i'm changing php.ini the `php --info` shows me different values of settings. What can it be?

Comment: is it an *untouched* centos installation? which version of centos?

Comment: what do you mean untouched? CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Comment: Untouched means: is this a regular centos php installation or are you using some management tool like confixx or whatever

Comment: regular yum install php-cli

Comment: Have tested to change the value of `display_errors` in `/etc/php.ini`. It works. (with a CentOS 6.3 as you) . Which ini settings do not work for you? Maybe they are overridden by a config file in `/etc/php.d` ?

Comment: display_errors doesn't changing values, in /etc/php.d only conf files for extensions, and i'm trying to set disable_functions for drush

Comment: Hard to say from remote what's the problem on your system. I could successfully disable functions using php.ini

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25723/discussion-between---and-hek2mgl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the value will not being overridden by other config files in `/etc/php.d`.